# Google calendar API delete / update recurring event returns 412 on URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to delete a parent recurring event (so the parent and all the instances will be deleted).

When using `URLSession` with manually constructed URLRequest the request returns **412** error code. I do not provide If-Match header and there have been no changes whatsoever to the event from the creation to its deletion.

Executing the request with Postman or Paw the request succeeds with status code **204** which is the desired result.

I construct the request as such:

```
 func delete(eventWithId eventId: String, token: String) {

    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)

    guard var URL = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/\(eventId)") else {return}
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL)
    request.httpMethod = "DELETE"

    request.addValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            let statusCode = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode // <--- returning status code 412
        }
        else {
            print("URL Session Task Failed: %@", error!.localizedDescription);
        }
    })
    task.resume()
    session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
}
```

The response body is:

```
{
   "error":{
      "errors":[
         {
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"conditionNotMet",
            "message":"Precondition Failed",
            "locationType":"header",
            "location":"If-Match"
         }
      ],
      "code":412,
      "message":"Precondition Failed"
   }
}
```

Weird thing. I do the same DELETE request using Postman and PAW and it succeeds, returning status code 204. Also my delete request seems to be working fine in single events or single occurrences of the recurring event.

Anyone with experience on the matter?

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code we need to be able to see what you are doing.

Comment: Very valid point @DaImTo . I did edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what was actually happening, was that there was a "If-None-Match" header added that wouldn't show up when I was debugging the request object. I had to audit the request using (Charles) proxy to see it.

Overriding this header field seems to have resolved this issue.